# Хочу добавить регистрацию через firebase в фрагменте, однако task заканчивается почему-то не успешно

Tags: android, android-fragment, firebase

Вот мой код:

```
public class RegisterFragment extends Fragment {

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser cUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(cUser!=null){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);

        EditText edRegisterLogin = v.findViewById(R.id.edRegisterLogin);
        EditText edRegisterPassword = v.findViewById(R.id.edRegisterPassword);
        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        Button register = v.findViewById(R.id.register);
        register.setOnClickListener(v1 -> {
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(edRegisterLogin.getText().toString())&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(edRegisterPassword.getText().toString())){
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(edRegisterLogin.getText().toString(), edRegisterPassword.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener( new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User sign up successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "User sign up failed");
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User sign up failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter Email and Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
}
```

То есть когда я ввожу данные пользователя, то он выдает мне "User sign up failed". В чем может быть проблема

Comment: Причин неудачи может быть много. Очень много, скорее всего, для их описания не хватит лимита символов в ответе. При этот мы не сможем воспроизвести у себя именно вашу проблему, т.к. нам не хватает данных. Отсюда два выхода: 1 - вы предоставляете всю информацию, включая весь код, версию ОС, все настройки из облачной консоли гугла и firebase etc, возможно, эта информация уместится в лимит символов вопроса. 2 - выведите в логи ошибку авторизации, она должна быть у вас в переменной `task` - скорее всего сразу станёт всё ясно. Если нет - добавьте в вопрос эту информацию - попробуем помочь.

Comment: Я нашёл ошибку, оказывается, если почту вводить неправильно, то есть без @, то она не будет работать